# Loop fails at assigning list to key in a map: Error: nosuchmethoderror: the method '[]=' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the code below fails to execute. In VisualStudio I don't get an error, but in the Android emulator I get the error listed in the Title. The code is looping through a list of Map objects as such:

```
[{"HappinessLevel": "0.4", "Date": "5/10/2021", "SadnessLevel": "0.2", "AngrinessLevel": "0.2", "SurpriseLevel": "0.3", "Diary": "123124215", "FearLevel": "0.1", "User": "a4b68"}, ... ]
```

The list is returned from an HTTP request made in the following code

```
RestOptions options = RestOptions(path: '/emotions/$userId');
RestOperation restOperation = Amplify.API.get(restOptions: options);
RestResponse response = await restOperation.response;

res = String.fromCharCodes(response.data);
resList = jsonDecode(res)
```

The code that fails is:

```
List resList;
Map<String, List> ret;

for (var i = 0; i < resList.length; i++) {
  String dVal = resList[i]["Date"];
  
  List lit = [
    double.parse(resList[i]["HappinessLevel"]),
    double.parse(resList[i]["SadnessLevel"]),
    double.parse(resList[i]["AngrinessLevel"]),
    double.parse(resList[i]["FearLevel"]),
    double.parse(resList[i]["SurpriseLevel"])
  ];
  
  ret[dVal] = lit; //Code fails here and loop terminates early on the first pass.
  
}
```

I know this snippet can be simplified, but I have been so desperate to determine where the failure happens, that I deconstructed the process.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```dart
Map<String, List> ret;
```

`ret` is currently null, and any attempts of putting a key into it will raise a `NullPointerException`.

When you do

```dart
Map<String, List> ret = {};
```

`ret` is currently an empty map, and you can put a key into it normally.